# Complete Elliptical Integral for the parameters greater than 1 or less than -1

Tags: elliptic-integrals

I am trying to compute the Complete elliptical integral of second kind kind in Mathematica with Parameter m=-19.7 .Following is the response from Mathematica.

Input:EllipticE[-19.71]
Output:4.81841

I want to know if this is correct or rather how does Mathematica calculate Elliptical integrals for the parameters outside the prescribed range 
(-1

Comment: can you show us your integral?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. Why do you think the output you get is  wrong?

EllipticE[m] in Mathematica means the following integral -

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-m\sin(t)}dt\,.
$$

The integrand is well defined for all $ m $ and so you should expect a proper answer for all m as well. For $ m\le 1 $, this gives a real number (as you got) and for $ m > 1 $, you will get a complex number.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Shaun This is not a new question; rather, this is an explanation of some properties of the elliptic integral.

Comment: @anorton Ah, I see. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm sorry about that, @udit

Comment: Thanks Shaun! I guess the initial doubts which I had were due to ambiguity in formulation of elliptical integral from different references. It's resolved now!